# Extract all percentage numbers from a data frame column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `df` with a character column `text` that contains text. From that column, I would like to extract all percentage numbers (say, 1.2% and -2.3%) but not the ordinary numbers (say, 123 and 1.2) into a character vector.

A small example:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("this text is 1.3% this is +1.4% and this -1.5%",
                          "this text is 123.3% this 123.3 and this 1234.5"))
```

Required output:

```
[1] "1.3%" "-1.4%"  "-1.5%" "123.3%"
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most robust general-purpose solution, but works for your example:

```
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(df$text, "[+\\-]?[0-9\\.]+%"))
#[1] "1.3%"   "+1.4%"  "-1.5%"  "123.3%"

## or using R's native forward pipe operator, since R 4.1.0
stringr::str_extract_all(df$text, "[+\\-]?[0-9\\.]+%") |> unlist()
#[1] "1.3%"   "+1.4%"  "-1.5%"  "123.3%"
```

This meets your expected output (i.e., a character vector). But in case you are thinking about storing the results to a new data frame column, you don't really want to `unlist()`. Just do:

```
df$percentages <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$text, "[+\\-]?[0-9\\.]+%")
df
#                                            text        percentages
#1 this text is 1.3% this is +1.4% and this -1.5% 1.3%, +1.4%, -1.5%
#2 this text is 123.3% this 123.3 and this 1234.5             123.3%
```

The new column `percentages` itself is a list:

```
str(df$percentages)
#List of 2
# $ : chr [1:3] "1.3%" "+1.4%" "-1.5%"
# $ : chr "123.3%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `tidyverse` way:

First we extract the numbers with `parse_number` from `readr` package,and then within an `ifelse` statement we specify the combination of number and percent. Finally `pull` for vector output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = parse_number(text),
         x = ifelse(str_detect(text, "%"), paste0(x,"%"), NA_character_)) %>% 
  pull(x)
```

```
1] "1.3%"   "1.4%"   "-1.5%"  "123.3%" NA       NA
```